# Use Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization to find the first 4 terms of the orthonormal sequence obtained from...

Tags: functional-analysis

Use Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization to find the first 4 terms of  the orthonormal sequence obtained from

$S=({x^n})_{n \epsilon N}$ in $L^2(0,1)=(\int^1_0 f^2(x)dx)^\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What kind of objects does the Gram-Schmidt process yield? What's a "vector" in $L^2(0,1)$? What's a vector in $\ell^2$? What kind of objects are your answers?

Comment: I need the components of the vectors for both parts of this question. I have edited my post to included the definitions of $L^2(0,1)$ and $l^2$.

Comment: The elements of $L^2$ are functions. The elements of $\ell^2$ are sequences. Your answers are real numbers, not vectors in either of these spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly,
$$
    P_{0} = 1.\\
$$
Notice that $\|P_{0}\|=1$. Then
$$
    Q_{1}=x-(x,P_{0})P_{0}=x-\frac{1}{2}1
$$
is orthogonal to $P_{0}$, and leads to $P_{1}=\|Q_{1}\|^{-1}Q_{1}$, where
$$
       \|Q_{1}\|^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}(x-1/2)^{2}\,dx=\left.\frac{1}{3}(x-1/2)^{3}\right|_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^{3}}.
$$
So
$$
        P_{1}=2\sqrt{6}(x-1/2).
$$
Next,
$$
      Q_{2}=x^{2}-(x^{2},P_{1})P_{1}-(x^{2},P_{0})P_{0},
$$
is orthogonal to $P_{0}$ and $P_{1}$, and leads to and $P_{2}=\|Q_{2}\|^{-1}Q_{2}$. This is the pattern of the Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: How would I use this process to do $l^2$?

Comment: The process is the same regardless of the underlying inner-product space. I'm not sure I understand the question in your comment; could your be more specific?